# Jmeter regex failing

Tags: jmeter

How do I get the text "Need to grab this" using Jmeter - Regex

"suggestionsIdentifiers":[{"#v":"some other variable","#t":"string"}],"saveInto":["need to grab this"],"labelPosition":"ADJACENT","#t":"PickerField"}]}]}

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very recommended to use Regular Expressions to work with JSON entities as they're quite complex, multiline, you need to escape a lot of characters, etc. so regular expressions are hard to develop and quite fragile.

I would recommend switching to [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/), it works with JSON like a charm.

JSON Path expression would be something like:

```
$..saveInto[0]
```

N.B. your response is not full, it doesn't look like a valid JSON so if you have any problems - please update your question with the full response so we could suggest an appropriate JSON Path

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (Scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for plugin installation instructions and some form of JSONPath language reference.